# Strange "Shadow Lines" In Webkit

Tags: html, css

An issue I'm having is strange lines appearing in certain situations. So far I only notice the issue in Webkit browsers. Also, I know my HTML is not done in the most efficient way, but for the purposes of my project, I would like it to remain the same, unless it is the cause of the issue. For my current work, it happens when I highlight text, or click certain things.  This is a big issue since highlighting will be done a lot on my page.  Please see my example below, note the extra blue areas in the first image are caused by highlighting text (not shown).

[image]

As you can see, when the page loads the lines are not present, however — after using the page for a bit, lines like this appear.

I did my best to recreate the problem in JS fiddle, and I was actually able to. If you highlight text, and then click off the text, you should see a line appear.

[Here is my JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/23ubnpky/)

Here is a a picture of the issue reproduced in JSFiddle.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="background-image">
        <div class="background-color"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>Highlight all text</div>
        <div>Keep going!</div>
        <div>Then click off to deselect</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.background-image{
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/4pgHkXy.png') repeat;
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05,1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05,1.05);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.background-color {
    background: #00adee;
    opacity: .5;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: aboslute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    }

.box { 
    background: #fff;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}

.box div {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

If I had to make a guess, I would assume it has something to do with the blur effect?

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Add information about specific browsers and OS. I can't see this issue in Chrome/Safari on OS X.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, Windows 7.

Comment: Can't reproduce it in latest Chrome (43.0.2357.65) on Windows 7 (32-bit) and Window 8.1 (32-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Also reproducible on Mac OS X / Latest Chrome.

This is a bug in Webkit that seems to be caused by combining `transform:scale` with `filter:blur`. If I remove the transform in the jsfiddle, the glitch is no longer reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/2fr6tcgz/

If the only reason you're using scale is to hide the blurry edges of the background, you could use `background-size: 105% auto; background-position: center center;` as a workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/xa23ja88/ (I also fixed the `position: aboslute;` typo).

Update:

Apparently the above doesn't fix it completely. But this does: https://jsfiddle.net/o0mupqbo/ (switching the nesting of background image and color). Does that work in your situation?

Comment: That is exactly the reason I used transform:scale - when back at my PC I will test this out.  Thanks.

Comment: Still receiving the same issue in both the fiddles and my project.  The only fix I've found is not using blur at all.

Comment: @DRBC in https://jsfiddle.net/xa23ja88/? because I could reproduce in your fiddle, but not in xa23ja88